# Unable to convert firebase anonymous user to permanent in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to convert a firebase user from Anonymous to permanent using email/password and running into errors.

The documentation and other articles state that I should linkWithProvider but it throws an exception that the email should be verified first, however, doing so throws another exception asking me to login first.

Here are snippets of what I tried so far

```
final emailAuthCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
  email: email,
  password: password,
);

await currentUser.linkWithProvider(emailAuthCredential);
```

> FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/operation-not-allowed] Please verify the new email before changing email.)

```
final emailAuthCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
  email: email,
  password: password,
);

await currentUser.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(email);
```

> FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/requires-recent-login] This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.)

Comment: I've encountered this issue too. The error indicates that the email address must first be verified but there's no way AFAIK to trigger sending the email to the address without first signing in as the new user, possibly losing access to the anonymous account??

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code**

```
linkUser()async{
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

if (user != null && user.isAnonymous) {
  try {
    // Prompt the user to enter their email and password
    String email = 'user@example.com'; // Replace with the user's input
    String password = 'password123';   // Replace with the user's input

    // Link the user to the email and password provider
    AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    await user.linkWithCredential(credential);

    // Now, the user is converted to a permanent user with email and password
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error linking anonymous user: $e');
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately same issue. It triggers the same exception to verify the email first. 

FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/operation-not-allowed] Please verify the new email before changing email.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the documentation (duh...). You now have to use the identity platform API and call signup with the anonymous token.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to email enumeration protection which is active by default on Firebase accounts created after September 2023.

When this feature is active numerous auth functions no longer work. Specifically, concerning this question:

> You can no longer use the linkWithCredential client SDK method with an
> EmailAuthCredential on any platform. Use the REST API signUp instead,
> passing the user's ID token in the idToken field and the email,
> password fields to link.

source : https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection

and here is the link to the sign up api that should now be used:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signUp